What is the artists name and seal (Characters identified: 雋香)
My mom acquired this painting from a box labeled "free" and is giving it to me. I've tried to trace the origins and posted on reddit and Facebook groups and haven't been able to find a concrete answer on the name of the signature or the year/decade it was created. [[![back of painting on frame[![corner picture of painting detail


I added a full frame photo of the painting


A close up and different angle of painting
